# WP7 Button inside ListBox only "clicks" every other press

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

I have a button defined inside of a DataTemplate for my list box.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>        
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="12,12,24,12">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Column="0" Name="EnableDisableButton" 
                    Click="EnableDisableButton_Click" 
                    BorderBrush="Transparent">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="\Images\img.dark.png" Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeVisibility}" />
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="\Images\img.light.png" Width="48" Height="48" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeVisibility}" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Width="48" Height="8" Fill="{Binding CurrentColor}" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
              <... more stuff here ...>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

What I'm seeing is that the first time I press the button, the Click event fires.  The second time I press it, it does not fire.  Third press, fires.  Fourth press, does not fire.  Etc.  Originally I had it bound to a command but that was behaving the same way.  (I put a Debug.WriteLine() in the event handler so I know when it fires.)

Any ideas?  It's really odd that the click event only fires every other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one the following two "workarounds":

1. In your click event callback set the focus back to the page: `this.Focus();`
2. In your click event callback set the `SelectedItem` of your `ListBox` to null: `myListBox.SelectedItem = null;`

I think one of the two should work...

click event callback = `EnableDisableButton_Click` method

Comment: Setting `this.Focus()` in the event callback worked.  Thanks!